# Is Channel.isWritable() can be used correctly from non I/O thead?

Tags: netty

In `Channel`'s javadoc it doesn't say `isWritable()` shouldn't be used by different threads than its I/O thread. So I assume the answer should be yes. But in the `Channel.Unsafe` javadoc it is said that its method must be invoked from the I/O thread (except few). 
`AbstractChannel.isWritable()` is implemented by calling the unsafe code to return the `outboundBuffer` and call on it `isWritable()`.
So isn't it violates what's instructed in the `Unsafe` javadoc if `Channel.isWriable()` is called from non I/O thread?

Isn't the fact that `AbstractChannel.AbstractUnsafe#outboundBuffer` (the reference) is not final and not volatile makes it possibly never visible to other threads than the channel's I/O thread (the event loop)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed in 4.0.39.Final and 4.1.3.Final by changing AbstractChannel.AbstractUnsafe#outboundBuffer to be volatile.
http://netty.io/news/2016/07/15/4-0-39-Final-4-1-3-Final.html

So on these builds and on it should be safe to use Channel.isWritable() from any thread.